# Maven Surefire: (Re-)Loading classes for isolated testing in forks

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to configure Maven Surefire to always fork a new JVM process for each test and reload *all* `.class` files that are necessary within that test inside that newly forked process.
I thought this was realizable with `forkCount=1` and `reuseForks=false` (for maximal isolation of tests), but this does not work, as tests (i.e., JVM forks) will not reload a `.class` file if it has already been loaded by a previously run test.

I've tried using the isolated class loader rather than the system class loader, but that did not affect this problem.
Right now I'm starting my test execution like this: `mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=false -f PATH_TO_PROJECT`.

Thank you.

EDIT: My desired behavior seems to be the default on Surefire `2.19.1`. Unfortunately, other things break with JDK>=11 with Surefire `2.19.1`. I have not figured out what has changed since then, but would appreciate hints on that.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need such things?

Comment: Sure, it's for understanding the characteristics of each test case. I want to know which files are touched by a test case only by looking at `open` syscalls without further code instrumentation.

Comment: If you have unit tests which are using external resources those tests are not unit tests...

Comment: Yet, a unit test will still load at least one .class file (where the unit under test is, i.e., method or class depending on your definition). Did not say I'm limiting myself to unit tests, though.